# How to unlock all the achievements

Tags: pc, mass-effect

I used to play Mass Effect (1) in the past, and gotten nearly all achievements - which was nice for my second playthrough, since unlike many other video game achievements, those actually give you something. Now I want to play the game again, but I since got a new PC and I have a feeling it won't remember what I had. I don't have the data from the old PC anymore, so essentially I'm asking for a way to cheat.

Is there a way to unlock some, or all, of those achievements? I'm playing it on the PC.

If it makes any difference, the last time I played was without Steam, but now I'm going to play with it.

Comment: Did you transfer all of your saved data over? Was ME1 played with Steam or Origin?

Comment: If you used steam, this is a non-issue, otherwise Mario's answer should work (`<my documents>\BioWare\Mass Effect`)

Comment: @CyberSkull whoops... updated the question to clarify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a solution [here](https://masseffect.fandom.com/wiki/PC_Tweaks#Achievements). In summary:

1. Enable the console
2. Go to `My Documents\Bioware\Mass Effect\Config`
3. Open the `BIOInput.ini` file with a text editor
4. Under the `[Engine.Console]`, add the `ConsoleKey=Tilde` line
5. Unlock achievements
6. Start the game
7. Open the in-game console by hitting the <kbd>`</kbd> key
8. Type `unlockachievement n` where `n` is a number between 1 and 47. They will unlock the achievement with that number. The site I linked has a full mapping between the number and the achievement, but I just went through and enabled them all.

Answer (score 5):

Go to `<my documents>\BioWare` and you should find a sub folder called `Mass Effect` (and others in case you've played the other games).

Just copy that folder to the same position on your new PC/hard drive and you should keep your progress as-is. In case you're playing over Origin, Origin might do the actual copying for you over the cloud (not sure it's supported for Mass Effect).

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have that folder anymore. Essentially I'm asking for a way to cheat and get those achievements from scratch.

Comment: You'd essentially have to edit the correct file, but that might get a bit complicated. I think I've seen an editor once, but it's probably been for save files only.